# Updating in mysql database using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have been trying to do the update the record in my database but i am getting the echo that the action have not being updated all i want is to update balance field in the database!
The following is the code in the controller where i take value that i have passed from ajax and i am passing the email and data to model.
Controller.

```
 public function transfer_amount(){


    $email  =  $this->input->post('view');



    $data = array(

            'balance' => $this->input->post('amount'),

    );

    $this->load->model('user_model');


    if($this->user_model->transfer_amount($data,$email)){


        echo'unsuccessfull';


    }
    else
    {

        $this->load->view('layer_service/success',$data);

    }



}
```

The Model which is supposed to update the field of the database is as following.

```
   function transfer_amount($data,$email){



    $this->db->where('email', $email);

    $this->db->update('tbl_users', $data);

        // Code here after successful insert
     // to the controller

    return true;


}
```

Comment: `echo $this->db->last_query();` and check the query.

Comment: ok let me add that then will tell you

Comment: UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `balance` = '1' WHERE `email` = ' mannie@layercaketz.com'     This is the output which i think its correct but still i am not getting it right.

Comment: Can you do a     var_dump($_POST); ?

Comment: What is the current value in the database? If it is the same value you try to update with, MySQL will return that it hasn't been updated (since it didn't need to)

Comment: The value is still 0 hasn't changed

Comment: I really need help please can you correct it

Comment: I have run the query inside database and it worked so i don't know whats is the problem

Comment: UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `balance` = '6' WHERE `email` = ' mannie@layercaketz.com'  i have realised that there is a space before the mail when i run it inside the database by removing the space it works so how do i remove the space before mail

Comment: Well, I don't think it's wrong; You're specifically telling it if it returned TRUE then it's unsuccessful which is weird (You got your if/else mixed up) otherwise you should be getting a success message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your above comment you need to trim the whitespace from the email.

```
function transfer_amount($data, $email) {

  $this->db->update('tbl_users', $data, array(
    'email' => trim($email),
  ));

  // Code here after successful insert
  // to the controller

  return true;
}
```

Also in your controller you will want to replace this line

```
if($this->user_model->transfer_amount($data,$email)){
```

with

```
if( ! $this->user_model->transfer_amount($data,$email)) {
```

As your model returns `TRUE` on success but your controller is expecting `FALSE` on success.

You can also check that your update was successful and did actually change some rows in the database using a simple if statement such as

```
if(0 >= $this->db->affected_rows()) {
  // update unsuccessful
}
```

**Update**

How to add to the current balance in MySQL. You can simply add to the value which is already in the database.

```
$data = array(
  'balance' => 'balance + ' . $this->input->post('amount'),
);
```

Comment: as i was able to update i came into an issue that i need to add the current value in the database with the one i am about to update the issue is working with mathematics i tried to add two array variables like` $data['user_balance'] = $this->user_model->fetch_balance($email);

        $data['balance'] = $this->input->post('amount');

        $data['total'] = $this->math->add($data['balance'],$data['user_balance']);


        $data = array(

                'balance' => $data['total'],

        );
`

Comment: This should be done fully in MySQL. See updated answer.